# django and executing a separate .py to manipute a database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to execute a random .py file, say foo.py on the myproject/myapp folder by using crobjob by some periods

I have this basic model in my model.py for the app:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

Say I have this in my foo.py, I want to check if there is any Mymodel object that has a content field as same as mytext, if not make a new Mymodel with the mytext as content, if already existing do nothing.

```
<do django importings>
mytext = "something here"
if Mymodel.filter(content=mytext) == null:
    newitem = Mymodel(content=mytext)
    newitem.save()
else:
    pass
```

So here is my question, what django imports shall I be doing? Also how can I check if the query has no item (don't know if if Mymodel.filter(content=mytext) == null would work. Also I don't know if this is an efficient way to achieve my goal as the amount of Mymodel will be high.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two separate questions here - it would have been better to split them out.

To run a separate script, you're best off creating a `./manage.py` command. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) on how to do this.

For your second question, the code you give is not valid Python, since there is no 'null' value - you mean `None`. However even then the code will not work, as that isn't how you write that query using the Django ORM. You want something like this:

```
if not MyModel.objects.filter(content=mytext).count():
```

which asks the database how many items there are with content=mytext, and is True if there are none.

Comment: thabjs alot daniel for the answer, do I need to import django and models while doing custom commands? The documentation lacks the detailed information

Comment: You always need to import your models if you're using them in your script, and whatever Django modules you're using. This is true of any Python code.

Answer (score 2):

You might also check out [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions), which has a built-in manage.py extension called "runscript" that executes any python script in your django project's context.